# PoS-SoP convertion of function bellow (NOT using K-map)

Tags: digital-logic

Function *F* as: $$ F=\overline{C} \space \space \overline{D} +A\overline{D} + A\overline{B}$$
is a SoP (sum of products) which is given by grouping K-map's 1's.

I tried to complement the function \$F\$ to get PoS (product of sums), like: $$ \overline{F}= (C+ D) \cdot (\overline{A}+D) \cdot (\overline{A}+B) $$ but I checked the K-map's 0's to see if it's a correct PoS, but it is not even a PoS because it contains max terms that the correct PoS  shouldn't have.

Does any one know where I'm wrong?

Comment: Multiply it out, reduce and invert a second time.  You've done DeMorgan's once.  You have to do it twice to go from PoS to SOP.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat does it work? I did and it didn't work

Comment: It works.  I did it.  Answer was the same as K-map.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat the answer is (C'+A')*(D'+A)*(B'+D') and when I draw the K-map it has wrong max terms.

Comment: Correction: I get  \$ f= (\overline B + \overline{D}) (A + \overline C) (A + \overline D ) \$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ F=\overline{C} \space \overline{D} +A\overline{D} + A\overline{B}$$

DeMorgan's

$$ \overline F=\overline{\overline{C} \space \overline{D} +A\overline{D} + A\overline{B}}$$

$$ \overline F= (C + D) (\overline A + D) (\overline A + B)$$

First two terms:
$$ \overline F= (C\overline A + D\overline A + CD + DD) (\overline A + B)$$

Simplify:
$$ \overline F= (C\overline A + D) (\overline A + B)$$

Finish multiplying out last term, reduce and take DeMorgan's.

That should get you to your answer.

---

[image: wide demo pic]

Comment: +1 for 3k+ rep. Yay... you earn new privileges!

Comment: Thanks.  For the couple times a month I lurk I here.  Rapidly down votes a couple of questions.